# ¿por qué virus total me manda la advertencia "Babable PUP.HighConfidence" cuando analizo mi archivo apk luego de hacer un build?

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

Resulta que he creado una aplicación en ionic 3, la aplicación ya pasó por testeo y ha sido pre aprobada, funcionalmente está bien.

El error resultó cuando fui a analizarla con ***virustotal*** que me ha saltado el error de virus

> Babable   PUP.HighConfidence  20180918

he buscado por varias fuentes para dar con una posible solución y no he leído nada que aporte.

**Mi App usa**

> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (fine (GPS) location)
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS (write contact data)
>   android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT (Unknown permission from android
>   reference) android.permission.READ_CONTACTS (read contact data)
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE (view network status)
>   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (coarse (network-based)
>   location) android.permission.INTERNET (full Internet access)
>   android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (modify/delete SD card
>   contents) android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS (discover known accounts)

además de esto, usa mensajería de texto y envío de correos.

No sé qué otro dato podría ser requerido.

Gracias

Comment: La apk esta accediendo a alguna funcionalidad extra no especificada verifica los permisos que requieres! Y especifica cada 1

Comment: Hola Byro, gracias por responde. Verificando la información de la App con lo que me indicabas, todo anda correctamente, los permisos de funcionalidades extras, están contemplados y autorizados por el usuario. Quizá esté dejando ir algo más. ¿podrías explicarme un poco más sobre esto por favor?. Gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

¡He encontrado la solución!

Luego, de buscar por muchos lugares sin solución, revisar permisos como anteriormente me habían sugerido, recrear permisos sin encontrar solución alguna, se nos ocurrió una idea ya que era lo último por hacer.

La solución a mi problema fue parcialmente sencilla, tan solo como
¡Firmar la aplicación!

**1. Primer paso**
Generar un archivo relase

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

**2. Segundo paso**
Dirigirte a la carpeta release de tu apk para generar el archivo de la firma

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**3. Tercer paso**
Firmar la aplicación con el archivo generado antiguamente

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Si tienes errores en este paso, verifica tu alias_name con el siguiente comando

```
keytool -keystore tu_nombre_key.keystore -list -v
```

Literalmente, saldrá una variable Aliase: tu_alias_name, la que deberás colocar al final del comando de jarsigner

**4. Cuarto paso**
Comprime tu apk utilizando zipaling

```
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

**Si te surge un error en este paso, instala zipaling**
Ruta del zipaling

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/TU_VERSION/zipalign
```

Añada el path en mac

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Agrega el comando a los builds del home

```
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.2' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Recarga la línea de comandos

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Corre nuevamente tu zpling

```
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

De esta manera, he solucionado el error del supuesto "Virus"

> Babable PUP.HighConfidence 20180918

Feliz tarde y espero que le pueda ayudar a alguien en su futuro si no habrían encontrado solución a esto.